# C# how to get changed display settings

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, display, dpi

The app uses event to get display setting change.

```
SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged;
```

When new display is added app moves to new display. Inside event listener the app calculates its new cordinates. The problem is that app still gets old display settings and uses it to draw itself on the new display.

```
double dpi = 1;
using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    dpi = g.DpiX / 96;
}
```

This is how the app gets DPI of the display. Here it gets old display DPI.
Can you help to solve this issue. Maybe there is a way to force .Net to load display  settings again?

Comment: Is your app DPI aware? Per-monitor aware?

Comment: My laptop DPI is 150% and monitor display DPI is 100%. When I start the app on the laptop or start the app when display is connected the app retrieves DPI correctly. The problem happens when I start the app on laptop and connect the display, then the app still gets 150% DPI when drawn on the display.

Comment: Have you marked yourself per-monitor v2 aware in your app manifest?

Comment: @Anders No, I will check that

Comment: This old snippet no longer works well regardless of DPI awareness of app. Instead, use VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi method to get current DPI and override OnDpiChanged method to catch DPI change event.